# SQL/BigQuery text classification

Tags: sql, text, google-bigquery, text-mining, mining

I need to implement a simple text classification using regex, and for this I thought to apply a simple CASE WHEN statement, but rather than in case one condition is met, I want to iterate over all the CASEs.

For example,

```sql
with `table` as(
SELECT 'It is undeniable that AI will change the landscape of the future. There is a frequent increase in the demand for AI-related jobs, especially in data science and machine learning positions. It is believed that artificial intelligence will change the world, just like how electricity changed the world about 100 years ago. As Professor Andrew NG has famously stated multiple times “Artificial Intelligence is the new electricity.” We have advanced immensely in the field of artificial intelligence. With the increase in the processing and computational power, thanks to graphical processing units (GPUs), and also due to the abundance of data, we have reached a position of supremacy in Deep Learning and modern algorithms.' as text
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)ai') THEN 'AI'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)computational power') THEN 'Engineering'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)deep learning') THEN 'Deep Learning'
  END as topic,
  text
FROM `table`
```

With this query, the text is classified as AI, because it is the first condition that is met, but it should be classified as AI, Engineering and [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) in an array or in three different rows, because all three conditions are met.

How can I classify the text applying all the regex/conditions?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the below is the most generic and reusable solution (BigQuery Standard SQL):

```
#standardSQL
with `table` as(
select 'It is undeniable that AI will change the landscape of the future. There is a frequent increase in the demand for AI-related jobs, especially in data science and machine learning positions. It is believed that artificial intelligence will change the world, just like how electricity changed the world about 100 years ago. As Professor Andrew NG has famously stated multiple times “Artificial Intelligence is the new electricity.” We have advanced immensely in the field of artificial intelligence. With the increase in the processing and computational power, thanks to graphical processing units (GPUs), and also due to the abundance of data, we have reached a position of supremacy in Deep Learning and modern algorithms.' as text
), classification as (
  select 'ai' term, 'AI' topic union all
  select 'computational power', 'Engineering' union all
  select 'deep learning', 'Deep Learning'
), pattern as (
  select r'(?i)' || string_agg(term, '|') as regexp_pattern
  from classification
)
select
   array_to_string(array(
    select distinct topic
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(lower(text), regexp_pattern)) term
    join classification using(term)
   ), ', ') topics,
  text
from `table`, pattern
```

With output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One method is string concatenation:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)ai') THEN 'AI;' ELSE '' END,
              CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)computational power') THEN 'Engineering;' ELSE '' END,
              CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)deep learning') THEN 'Deep Learning;' ELSE '' END
            ) as topics, text
FROM `table`;
```

Actually, this constructs a string.  You can use similar-ish logic to construct an array instead.

Comment: exactly what I needed, I use your answer and modified a little to get an array like result

Comment: this looks unreadable, but gets me where I want
`SELECT ARRAY(SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)ai') THEN 'AI' ELSE '' END as topics FROM table UNION ALL
             SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)computational power') THEN 'Engineering' ELSE '' END as topics FROM table UNION ALL
             SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)deep learning') THEN 'Deep Learning' ELSE '' END as topics FROM table
            ) as topics, text
FROM table;`

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
select
   array_to_string(array(select distinct lower(topic)
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(text, r'(?i)ai|computational power|deep learning')) topic
   ), ', ') topics,
  text
from `table`
```

If applying it to sample data from your question, the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As this question suddenly bubbled up, I decided to update it with an answer involving recent features—the [ML.UNDERSTAND_TEXT function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-understand-text) and [ML.GENERATE_TEXT function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-generate-text)

See an example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION EXTRACT_CATEGORY(text STRING) AS ((
SELECT trim(string(ml_understand_text_result['categories'][0].name), '"/"')
  FROM ML.UNDERSTAND_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_nl`,
  (SELECT text AS text_content),
  STRUCT('CLASSIFY_TEXT' AS nlu_option)
)));
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION PICK_CATEGORY(text STRING) AS ((
SELECT TRIM(STRING(ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content']), '" ')
  FROM ML.GENERATE_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_llm`,
  (SELECT FORMAT('Please identify which categories is most applicable for following text "%s". Include all applicable as a comma separated list. The options are: AI or Engineering or Deep Learning', text)  AS prompt)
)));
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT "It is undeniable that AI will change the landscape of the future. There is a frequent increase in the demand for AI-related jobs, especially in data science and machine learning positions. It is believed that artificial intelligence will change the world, just like how electricity changed the world about 100 years ago. As Professor Andrew NG has famously stated multiple times “Artificial Intelligence is the new electricity.” We have advanced immensely in the field of artificial intelligence. With the increase in the processing and computational power, thanks to graphical processing units (GPUs), and also due to the abundance of data, we have reached a position of supremacy in Deep Learning and modern algorithms." AS text UNION ALL
  SELECT "Structural engineers utilize advanced materials and techniques to ensure the stability of buildings and bridges. By integrating computer-aided design (CAD) with real-world data, innovative solutions arise, improving both safety and cost-efficiency in infrastructural projects." AS text
)
SELECT PICK_CATEGORY(text) AS category1, EXTRACT_CATEGORY(text) AS category2, text
FROM sample_data
```

With output:

[image]